# Python decorator to ensure that kwargs are correct

Tags: python

I have done a decorator that I used to ensure that the keyword arguments passed to a constructor are the **correct/expected ones**. The code is the following:

```
from functools import wraps

def keyargs_check(keywords):
"""
This decorator ensures that the keys passed in kwargs are the onces that
are specified in the passed tuple. When applied this decorate will
check the keywords and will throw an exception if the developer used
one that is not recognized.

@type keywords: tuple
@param keywords: A tuple with all the keywords recognized by the function.
"""

def wrap(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def newFunction(*args, **kw):
        # we are going to add an extra check in kw
        for current_key in kw.keys():
            if not current_key in keywords:
                raise ValueError(
                    "The key {0} is a not recognized parameters by {1}.".format(
                        current_key, f.__name__))
        return f(*args, **kw)
    return newFunction
return wrap
```

An example use of this decorator would be the following:

```
class Person(object):

@keyargs_check(("name", "surname", "age"))
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # perform init according to args
```

Using the above code if the developer passes a key args like "blah" it will **throw an exception**. Unfortunately my implementation has a major problem with inheritance, if I define the following:

```
class PersonTest(Person):

@keyargs_check(("test"))
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    Person.__init__(self,**kwargs)
```

Because I'm passing kwargs to the super class init method, I'm going to get an exception because "test" **is not in the tuple** passed to the decorator of the super class. Is there a way to let the decorator used in the super class to know about the extra keywords? or event better, is there a standard way to achieve what I want?

Update: I am more interested in automate the way I throw an exception when a developer passes the wrong kwarg rather than on the fact that I use kwargs instead of args. What I mean is, I do not want have to write the code that check the args passed to the method in every class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decorator is not necessary.  The only thing the decorator does that can't be done with the standard syntax is prevent keyword args from absorbing positional arguments.  Thus

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(name=None,surname=None,age=None):
        #some code

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(test=None,**kwargs):
        Base.__init__(self,**kwargs)
```

The advantage of this is that `kwargs` in `Child` will not contain `test`.  The problem is that you can muck it up with a call like `c = Child('red herring')`.  This is [fixed in python 3.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

The problem with your approach is that you're trying to use a decorator to do a macro's job, which is unpythonic.  The only thing that will get you what you want is something that modifies the locals of the innermost function (`f` in your code, specifically the `kwargs` variable).  How should your decorator know the wrapper's insides, how would it know that it calls a superclass?

Comment: I understand you point of view, and I did think about using *args, but that gives me a problem, I do not want to have to do the following:

example = Base(u"", u"", 26)

and will prefer to use:

example = Base(age=29)

The reasoning of using kwargs is that I have lots of arguments and I do not want the developer to have to pass all the default values!

Comment: The way David wrote the code, you don't have to supply the default arguments.  You can construct a Base with Base(age=29).

Comment: Indeed, but I want to perform the check in every class and I though that the use of a decorator would increase the code reuse. I do not want to have to add the check in every object. I prefer the use of a decorator but even if I use a function, I would have the same problem.