# How can you set class attributes from variable arguments (kwargs) in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a class with a constructor (or other function) that takes a variable number of arguments and then sets them as class attributes conditionally.

I could set them manually, but it seems that variable parameters are common enough in python that there should be a common idiom for doing this.  But I'm not sure how to do this dynamically.

I have an example using eval, but that's hardly safe.  I want to know the proper way to do this -- maybe with lambda?

```
class Foo:
    def setAllManually(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):
        if a!=None: 
            self.a = a
        if b!=None:
            self.b = b
        if c!=None:
            self.c = c
    def setAllWithEval(self, **kwargs):
        for key in **kwargs:
            if kwargs[param] != None
                eval("self." + key + "=" + kwargs[param])
```

Comment: It looks like these questions are similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884612/automatically-setting-class-member-variables-in-python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356718/how-to-handle-constructors-or-methods-with-a-different-set-or-type-of-argument http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446555/python-decorator-to-ensure-that-kwargs-are-correct so it looks like what I want is maybe this-- self.__dict__[key] = kwargs[key]

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but you might want to check [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a few hints on conventional Python styling.

Comment: There is a fantastic library for this called attrs.  simply `pip install attrs`, decorate your class with `@attr.s`, and set the args as `a = attr.ib(); b = attr.ib()` etc.  Read more [here](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/attrs.html).

Comment: Am I missing something here?
You still need to do self.x =kwargs.get'x'] 
You open yourself up to typos from caller
You have to create client with extra chars
instance=Class(**{})
If you don't jump thru hoops with the self.x =kwargs.get'x'] mundaneness, isn't it going to bite you later anyway? i.e. Instead of self.x, you 'll end up with self.__dict__['x'] down the line right? Or getattr() Either more typing than self.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You could update the `__dict__` attribute (which represents the instance attributes in the form of a dictionary) with the keyword arguments:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

then you can:

```
>>> bar = Bar(a=1, b=2)
>>> bar.a
1
```

and with something like:

```
allowed_keys = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
self.__dict__.update((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in allowed_keys)
```

you could filter the keys beforehand (use `iteritems` instead of `items` if you’re still using Python 2.x).

Comment: Even better if you use `self.__dict__.update(locals())` to copy also positional arguments.

Comment: I think you'll need this nowadays..  kwargs[0].items() instead of kwargs.iteritems() - (I'm using Python 3.6.5 at time of writing)

Comment: @JGFMK Why `kwargs[0]` instead of just `kwargs`? Can `kwargs` even have an integer key? I'm pretty sure they have to be strings.

Comment: Do you mean "which represents the instance attributes..."?

Comment: @jsp99 you’re right, fixed it. Funny nobody else stumbled across it in nine years :)

Answer (score 183):

You can use the [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) method:

```
class Foo:
  def setAllWithKwArgs(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
      setattr(self, key, value)
```

There is an analogous [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) method for retrieving attributes.

Comment: @larsks thanks but any idea how we could unpack only a dictionary key? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792761/calling-and-using-an-attribute-stored-in-variable-using-beautifulsoup-4

Comment: Do you need to use `.getattr()`? Or can you access the attributes with `Foo.key`?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro you can of course just use `Foo.attrname`.  I think I was just pointing out the fact that the `getattr` method exists.  It's also useful if you want to provide a default value for when the named attribute isn't available.

Comment: What is the difference with the [accepted answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187408/6655465). What their pros and cons?

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli IMO this is much clearer to the reader.

Answer (score 20):

Most answers here do not cover a good way to initialize all allowed attributes to just one default value.
So, to add to the answers given by [@fqxp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187408/3357935) and [@mmj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019483/3357935):

```
class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # all those keys will be initialized as class attributes
        allowed_keys = set(['attr1','attr2','attr3'])
        # initialize all allowed keys to false
        self.__dict__.update((key, False) for key in allowed_keys)
        # and update the given keys by their given values
        self.__dict__.update((key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items() if key in allowed_keys)
```

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer due to the inizialization to `False`. Good point!

Comment: Actually the initialization to `False` makes this answer **less** flexible than the others.

Answer (score 16):

I propose a variation of [fqxp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187408/3357935), which, in addition to ***allowed attributes***, lets you set ***default values*** for attributes:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # define default attributes
        default_attr = dict(a=0, b=None, c=True)
        # define (additional) allowed attributes with no default value
        more_allowed_attr = ['d','e','f']
        allowed_attr = list(default_attr.keys()) + more_allowed_attr
        default_attr.update(kwargs)
        self.__dict__.update((k,v) for k,v in default_attr.items() if k in allowed_attr)
```

This is Python 3.x code, for Python 2.x you need at least one adjustment, `iteritems()` in place of `items()`.

#### VERY LATE FOLLOW UP

I recently rewrote the above code as a ***class decorator***, so that hard coding of attributes is reduced to a minimum. In some way it resembles some features of [the `@dataclass` decorator](http://zetcode.com/python/dataclass/), which is what you might want to use instead.

```
# class decorator definition
def classattributes(default_attr,more_allowed_attr):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        def new_init(self,*args,**kwargs):
            allowed_attr = list(default_attr.keys()) + more_allowed_attr
            default_attr.update(kwargs)
            self.__dict__.update((k,v) for k,v in default_attr.items() if k in allowed_attr)
        cls.__init__ = new_init
        return cls
    return class_decorator

# usage:
# 1st arg is a dict of attributes with default values
# 2nd arg is a list of additional allowed attributes which may be instantiated or not
@classattributes( dict(a=0, b=None, c=True) , ['d','e','f'] )
class Foo():
    pass # add here class body except __init__

@classattributes( dict(g=0, h=None, j=True) , ['k','m','n'] )
class Bar():
    pass # add here class body except __init__

obj1 = Foo(d=999,c=False)
obj2 = Bar(h=-999,k="Hello")

obj1.__dict__ # {'a': 0, 'b': None, 'c': False, 'd': 999}
obj2.__dict__ # {'g': 0, 'h': -999, 'j': True, 'k': 'Hello'}
```

Comment: This is the most flexible answer, summarizing the other approaches in this thread. It sets the attributes, allows for default values and adds only allowed attribute names. Works fine with python 3.x as shown here.

Answer (score 10):

Yet another variant based on the excellent answers by [mmj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019483/7382307) and [fqxp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187408/7382307). What if we want to

1. Avoid hardcoding a list of allowed attributes
2. *Directly* and explicitly set default values for each attributes in the constructor
3. Restrict kwargs to predefined attributes by either

   - silently rejecting invalid arguments *or*, alternatively,
   - raising an error.

By "directly", I mean avoiding an extraneous `default_attributes` dictionary.

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        # Predefine attributes with default values
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.A = True
        self.B = True

        # get a list of all predefined values directly from __dict__
        allowed_keys = list(self.__dict__.keys())

        # Update __dict__ but only for keys that have been predefined 
        # (silently ignore others)
        self.__dict__.update((key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items() 
                             if key in allowed_keys)

        # To NOT silently ignore rejected keys
        rejected_keys = set(kwargs.keys()) - set(allowed_keys)
        if rejected_keys:
            raise ValueError("Invalid arguments in constructor:{}".format(rejected_keys))
```

Not a major breakthrough, but maybe useful to someone...

**EDIT:**
If our class uses `@property` decorators to encapsulate "protected" attributes with getters and setters, and if we want to be able to set these properties with our constructor, we may want to expand the `allowed_keys` list with values from `dir(self)`, as follows:

```
allowed_keys = [i for i in dir(self) if "__" not in i and any([j.endswith(i) for j in self.__dict__.keys()])]
```

The above code excludes

- any hidden variable from `dir()` (exclusion based on presence of "__"), and
- any method from `dir()` whose name is not found in the end of an attribute name (protected or otherwise) from `__dict__.keys()`, thereby likely keeping only @property decorated methods.

This edit is likely only valid for Python 3 and above.

Answer (score 4):

The following solutions `vars(self).update(kwargs)` or `self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)` are not robust, because the user can enter any dictionary with no error messages. If I need to check that the user insert the following signature ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5') the solution does not work. Moreover, the user should be able to use the object by passing the "positional parameters" or the "kay-value pairs parameters".

So I suggest the following solution by using a metaclass.

```
from inspect import Parameter, Signature

class StructMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
        sig = cls.make_signature(clsobj._fields)
        setattr(clsobj, '__signature__', sig)
        return clsobj

def make_signature(names):
    return Signature(
        Parameter(v, Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD) for v in names
    )

class Structure(metaclass = StructMeta):
    _fields = []
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bond = self.__signature__.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, val in bond.arguments.items():
            setattr(self, name, val)

if __name__ == 'main':

   class A(Structure):
      _fields = ['a1', 'a2']

   if __name__ == '__main__':
      a = A(a1 = 1, a2 = 2)
      print(vars(a))

      a = A(**{a1: 1, a2: 2})
      print(vars(a))
```

Answer (score 3):

this one is the easiest via [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)

```
class Foo:
    def setAllWithKwArgs(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

my example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

door = Foo(size='180x70', color='red chestnut', material='oak')
print(door.size) #180x70
```

Comment: could smb explain what is kwargs.items()?

Comment: `kwargs` is a dictionary of keyword arguments, and `items()` is a method that returns a copy of the dictionary's list of `(key, value)` pairs.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I usually do:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, **kwrgs):
        allowed_args = ('a', 'b', 'c')
        default_values = {'a':None, 'b':None} 
        self.__dict__.update(default_values)
        if set(kwrgs.keys()).issubset(allowed_args):
            self.__dict__.update(kwrgs)
        else:
            unallowed_args = set(kwrgs.keys()).difference(allowed_args)
            raise Exception (f'The following unsupported argument(s) is passed to Foo:\n{unallowed_args}')
```

For most cases I find this short code enough.

**Note**

Using setattr with for loop can negatively impact the performance of your code especially if you create a lot of this class. In my test, replacing the `__update__` with `setattr(self, key, value)` in a for loop for the Foo class above, made the class take 1.4 times longer to instantiate. This will be worst if you have more arguments to set. The for loops are slow in python so this is not a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

```
class SymbolDict(object):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
      setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

x = SymbolDict(foo=1, bar='3')
assert x.foo == 1
```

I called the class `SymbolDict` because it essentially is a dictionary that operates using symbols instead of strings.  In other words, you do `x.foo` instead of `x['foo']` but under the covers it's really the same thing going on.

Answer (score 2):

Both the `setattr()` and `__dict__.update()` methods bypass property `@setter` functions.  The only way I have found to get this to work is by using `exec()`.

`exec` is considered a security risk, but we're not using it with any old user input, so I can't see why it would be.  If you disagree I'd really like to learn why, so please leave a comment.  I don't want to be advocating or committing insecure code.

My example is mostly borrowed from previous answers for completeness, but the main difference is the line `exec(f"self.{key} = '{value}'")`

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Predefine attributes with default values
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.name = " "
        

        # get a list of all predefined attributes
        allowed_keys = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not attr.startswith("_")]
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            # Update properties, but only for keys that have been predefined 
            # (silently ignore others)
            if key in allowed_keys:
                exec(f"self.{key} = '{value}'")

    @property
    def name(self):
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.firstname, self.lastname = name.split(" ", 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Their might be a better solution but what comes to mind for me is:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args=dict(**kwargs)

    def getkwargs(self):
        print(self.args)

t=Test(a=1, b=2, c="cats")
t.getkwargs()


python Test.py 
{'a': 1, 'c': 'cats', 'b': 2}
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is to conditionally set attributes based on validation.  I realized that the problem with using kwargs is that it doesn't validate (or document) which attributes are acceptable

Comment: Yeah I realize @larsks answer is better. Learn something new everyday at SO!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might be better in most instances to use named args (for better self documenting code) so it might look something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def setAll(a=None, b=None, c=None):
        for key, value in (a, b, c):
            if (value != None):
                settattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: This iteration does not work: `for key, value in (a, b, c)`

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this page with a subtly different question, but here's the answer I needed:

Try `namedtuple` class ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573457/93910)), or the `@dataclass` decorator ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263/what-are-data-classes-and-how-are-they-different-from-common-classes)).

These are built specifically with this kind of functionality in mind, but may be less flexible than the other answers here.