# Iterating over a list adding attributes to an object in Python

Tags: python

This is what I would like.

```
def add_things_to_x(x,list_of_things):
    for item in list_of_things:
        x.item = item
    return x
```

How can I do this?

And as it seems so hard to do I am guessing there may be a better way and a reason not to do this?

An example of how I might use such a function.

```
average_height = 10
std_height = 3

x = load_data()

x = add_things_to_x(x,[average_height,std_height])

x.save_data()
```

so that later on if I pickle.load(x) I could do call x.std_height and x.average_height

Comment: It's not clear what your question is; the code you showed works, but in the end you've set `x.item` to different values ending up with just the last one. Is that the intended outcome, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @WillBeauchamp Show us, how you want to use it and what results you expect.

Comment: You are right, it is ambiguous, let me try to change it.

Comment: You want to set *dynamic attributes*, and your call won't work because the *names* you want to set are no longer associated with the *values*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you set class attributes from variable arguments (kwargs) in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8187082) (already used my close vote for 'unclear what you are asking').

Comment: I could use setattr(x,'name',object) but I dont want to have to put in 2 bits of information {name,object}. Is there no way to intelligently and automatically get the 'name' from the object.

Comment: @WillBeauchamp No there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setattr` for that sort of thing:

```
for k, v in {'average_height': 10, 'std_height': 3}:
    setattr(x, k, v)
```

At the moment at the end you've set `x.item` to different values ending up with just the last one. This evades that problem because the name of the attribute is sent as a string parameter.

Comment: The OP *probably* wants to pass in key-value pairs; `x.average_height = 10`, etc.

Comment: @AlexThornton Could you provide full working example? So far I see unclear question and then your answer, which does not help me either.