# Set class attributes with keyword arguments

Tags: python, class

This popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python) addresses setting instance attributes with keyword arguments. However, I'd like to construct a class whose instances all have the same attributes based on some dictionary. How can this be achieved?

Here's my attempt. It seems I haven't quite understood something about class definitions.

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}


# Here's what I'd like to do
class A:
    __dict__ = d


# Answer from the linked question that works
class B:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


a = A()
b = B(**d)

# print(A.x)  # Has no attribute x
# print(a.x)  # Has no attribute x
print(b.x)
```

This is curious, because both `a.__dict__` and `b.__dict__` return the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to create a new class programmatically, with attributes based on the `dict` provided, so that all instances of the class will have those attributes?

Comment: @gmds Yes. My bad if it wasn't immediately clear.

Comment: What sense does is make to have all instances have the same attributes? What would be a valid use-case?

Comment: @KlausD. Using the class as a type of dynamic data storage. For me, creating a Flask configuration object. There may be better ways, after all there already exists such a method for utilising dictionaries: `from_mapping`. But as I started to look for the solution my question was "can I" rather than "should I". I love learning myself some new Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type` function can take arguments that allow it to create a new class dynamically:

```
B = type('B', (), d)

b = B()

print(b.x, b.y)
```

Output:

```
1 2
```

The first argument is the name of the generated class. The second is a `tuple` containing its base classes. In particular, the following two snippets are (roughly) equivalent:

```
class D(A, B, C):
    pass
```

and:

```
D = type('D', (A, B, C), {})
```

The last argument is a `dict` mapping names to attributes (both methods and values).