# Add attributes to object by init kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        # code

obj = Obj(a=5, b=10)
print(obj.a, obj.b) # 5 10
```

Is there a proven solution to this task?

Comment: `self.__dict__.update(kw)`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8187082/3001761, and please research in the future.

Comment: oh thx, just forgot that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you set class attributes from variable arguments (kwargs) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python)

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Just note that this is mostly an antipattern - there are very very few valid reasons to do this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's only applicable to python 2, in py3 you get `AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute 'update'`. Please research in the future. ;)

Comment: @JonasByström in Python 2.x this would be an old-style class, too

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to assign attributes passed in `**kw`:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        # in case of python 2, the following line is: for k, v in kw.iteritems():
        for k, v in kw.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

and then use the way you mentioned in your post:

```
obj = Obj(a=5, b=10)
print(obj.a, obj.b) # 5 10
```

Comment: @jonas-bystrom your edit is wrong as you can see here ```Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 13 2019, 19:58:14)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> k = {"a": "b"}
>>> k.iter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iter'
>>> k.items()
dict_items([('a', 'b')])```

Comment: @jonas it's called *items* in Python 3, as was already commented in the post

Comment: Syntax error in brain, sorry bout that! `iteritems()` is not present in py3 however so retried my fix with the correct name and reversed the comment as op's question was about py3.