# How to let Python Class take variable number of arguments with keywords and value

Tags: python-3.x, class

So I am working on one of the freecodecamp.org python assignments and one of the criteria is that I need to create a class. Quoting the assignment:

> The class should take a variable number of arguments that specify the number of balls of each color
> that are in the hat. For example, a class object could be created in any of these ways:

```
hat1 = Hat(yellow=3, blue=2, green=6)
hat2 = Hat(red=5, orange=4)
hat3 = Hat(red=5, orange=4, black=1, blue=0, pink=2, striped=9)
```

I have no idea how to construct a class that allows for objects to have a variable number of arguments with values. The class section on the website was very minimal and did not even cover variable arguments for keyword and values when constructing a class object. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Look up "kwargs" ("keyword arguments").

Comment: [How can you set class attributes from variable arguments (kwargs) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8187082)

Comment: I still don't get it.. I even copied and pasted an example code and it still does not work.. it seems you need to use a function for the **kwargs but if i define a function inside my class does it automatically execute it?

Comment: like can i have a class that takes **kwargs arguments??

Comment: never mind i got it

Answer (score 0):

Try googling around for python *args and **kwargs