# Most Pythonic and object-oriented way to create a class that collects together other objects?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

My real example is different, but I am going to explain it in terms of this made-up example.

I have some base abstract class such as `AbstractPerson`. I then have several specific persons which inherit from this, such as `Bob` and `Alice`.

```
class AbstractPerson:

    def __init__(self, age=1):
        "Abstract person base class."""
        self.age = age

    def interact(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Interaction not implemented.")

class Bob(AbstractPerson):

    def __init__(self, age=25):
        """Bob is a specific person."""
        super().__init__(age=age)

    def interact(self):
        return "Bob makes a joke."
    
class Alice(AbstractPerson):

    def __init__(self, age=23):
        """Alice is another specific person."""
        super().__init__(age=age)

    def interact(self):
        return "Alice laughs."
```

Now, I would like to create objects that are collections of **any number of persons**. What is the most Pythonic way of doing this? Examples are: lists, dictionaries, tuples, and using classes. I suppose, in an OOP framework, one ideally would create a class. What's the typical way of doing this? Here is one example, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187408/6435921).

```
class FriendGroup:

    def __init__(self, **persons_dict):
        self.__dict__.update(persons_dict)

    def interact():
        """The friends interact."""
        interaction = ""
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            interaction += self.key.interact()
        return interaction
```

Or is it better to create `FriendGroup` as inheriting from `AbstractPerson`?

The idea is that at some point I want to create a `FriendGroup` that contains any (finite) number of `AbstractPerson` and such that it is easy enough to "use" these instances. Something like:

```
bob = Bob(age=40)
second_bob = Bob(age=25)
alice = Alice(age=35)
friends = Friends(bob, alice, second_bob)
```

Then I want to be able to do things with these people.
I don't care about the names, just that they are all
inheriting from AbstractPerson and ideally have the
same methods and attributes.

Comment: What makes `Alice` and `Bob` need to be classes instead of instances of a `Person`? If there will only ever be a single `Alice` or `Bob` in your code this seems mis-designed.

Comment: @tzaman I'll think about this, I'm unclear if this is the case or not in my specific example.

Comment: Inheritence represents the IS-A relationship. A group of people is not a kind of person, so it should not be a subclass.

Comment: We can't really give a tutorial on OO design here, it's the kind of thing you might spend a week on in a programming class.

Comment: `FriendGroup` seems to make conceptual sense, but it's not clear what problem it solves. Beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). One thing is that, [if there aren't any other methods, maybe it shouldn't be a class](//youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0&t=179s). Beyond that, there's honestly so much wrong with the design here that unpacking that would take up most of the space of any answer to this question (e.g. Bob and Alice are conceptually not classes). Sorry, I think you just need to learn more OOP.

Comment: FWIW, one of the easier problems to fix is that friends aren't conceptually *attributes* of a friend group, but *elements* of it, so `FriendGroup` should probably be a container, say a [`MutableMapping`](//docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) of names to `Person`s. If a friend group had attributes, they would be things more like, when it was established, its name if any, its primary location if any (like, where most of the friends live), what common interests they have ... IDK, it depends what you're modelling.

Answer (score 1):

To propose an alternative, would something like this be sufficient for your use case? If not, it'd be illustrative to explain why not.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    interaction: str

    def interact(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.interaction}.'

bob = Person(name='Bob', age=37, interaction='makes a joke')
print(bob.interact())
# 'Bob makes a joke.'
```